# How to upload or save on FTP to /www folder on Ubuntu 12.04 localhost?

Tags: apache2, ftp

I just start to use Ubuntu as OS and would like to ask what's the best practice to use apache and save my files on /www saving by programs or FTP.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

If you have root privileges you can use sftp and [ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) for remote access.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You can even mount you remote folder, just add the following line to your fstab:

```
sshfs#username@ip:/var/www /media/mywww fuse  IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa,defaults,nonempty,allow_other,idmap=user,uid=userid,gid=usergrpu  0 0
```

Locally you can add your user to the www-data group:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the same computer, can't you just use:

```
sudo cp -r '/PATH/TO/FOLDER' '/www/OTHER-FOLDER'
```

This will copy the `/PATH/TO/FOLDER` directory to `/www/OTHER-FOLDER` - this should also work for files.

To move a folder, use `mv` instead of `cp`.

To remove a folder <sub>*Make sure it is the right folder...*</sub>:

```
sudo rm -r '/PATH/TO/FOLDER'
```